# twitter in drupal 7 web site

Tags: drupal, twitter

sir

I'm new to the drupal. I want to put twitter button in my drupal 7 web site in the footer.I use twitter button code to html.tpl.php file and i put code to the below the page bottom ().It works correctly.But button it display below the footer in my site.But i want to display twitter button in the footer.How can i do this.
I want only the log to my site's twitter page when clicking button.

this is the code which i use (https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#follow)

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/twitter" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large">Follow @twitter</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're best off using the [Twitter Follow Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter_follow) module or [Follow Button](https://www.drupal.org/project/followbutton) module or a similar one to do this for you.  They'll each give you a block which you can then place wherever you want, without having to manually add the code to your template.  You can then just go to the blocks page and move it to the region you wish to place it in and order it relative to the other items in that region using the drag handles on the left.

If you really want it completely custom coded in yourtemplate, you're probably looking for `page.tpl.php`, not `html.tpl.php`.  You won't have as much control over placement, though.